# What is the best way to transform data from an API in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, graphql

I have some data I'm getting back from an API call to GraphQL, which I would like to do some transformation to and then, have that transformed data sent back to the client. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do the transformation/preparation in the resolver function which is the middleware from the server to the client.

First you would have to modify the schema by adding the type definitions for the data that you want to be passed and claiming a query/mutation gql string.

Then you would have to provide the function (called a resolver) that would become  the handler.

More information in depth: [here](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-graphql-input-types-and-client-caching-f11fa0421cfd)